# Is there a way to require a checkbox field on a Log In form?

Tags: login

I've set up a standard exp:member:login form for members-only content. My client has requested that I add a checkbox field that would require users to check before they would be allowed to log in. It doesn't appear that the standard login form allows for "rules:" parameters. I've looked around on Devot-ee, and I haven't seen anything that looks like it would fit the bill.

Is there a way to do this using standard EE tags/parameters? Or maybe an add-on that would allow me to add this functionality? If not, do you have suggestions for how I might build this?

Comment: Without knowing your specific scenario - one thing to remember is that you are the expert on web design - not your client. Very few websites have a required checkbox in the login field, and it doesn't sound like a very nice user experience. So it might be worth discussing with your client whether this is really necessary :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use Javascript to require the field be checked?  That would seem to be the simplest solution to me, since it's just a couple of lines of JS to require it.  It could be gotten around by turning JS off of course, but unless it's legally vital, I wouldn't worry about that too much.

You can also, I believe, require custom fields using Profile:Edit or Zoo Visitor if you have either of those installed, since they both build off the SafeCracker tag that allows that.

Comment: I guess that was my next thing to consider. I'll give that a shot. I just didn't know if javascript validation was likely to conflict or interfere with the native EE validation.

Comment: Yep. A little javascript did the trick with no conflicts. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction.